# Mobx-react does not update component when observable.map value is changed

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

In my store ..

```
@observable dots = observable.map({
  '0x001': extendObservable({ x: 2000, y: 2000 }),
  '0x002': extendObservable({ x: 5000, y: 5000 }),
  '0x003': extendObservable({ x: 10000, y: 10000 }),
});

@action updateDot(id, properties) {
  const dot = this.dots.get(id);
  this.dots.set(id, extendObservable(Object.assign(dot, properties)));
}
```

When I update the dot values  ..

```
store.updateDot('0x002', {
  x: 200,
  y: 300,
});
```

My components do not react ..

```
@inject('store') @observer
export class IndexComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    const { store } = this.props;
    const { dots } = store;

    return <Map dots={dots} />
  }

}
```

And Map ..

```
@observer
class Map extends Component {
  render() {
    const { dots } = this.props;
    // NOT CALLED WHEN UPDATE DOTS
    return <Matrix dots={dots} />
  }
}
```

And Matrix ...

```
@observer
class Matrix extends Component {
  render() {
    const { dots, ...rest } = this.props;
    // NOT CALLED WHEN UPDATE DOTS
    return <div ...rest ></div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best set up a fiddle, as with that we can really verify a solution, but I think

```
@observable dots = observable.map({
  '0x001': { x: 2000, y: 2000 },
  '0x002': { x: 5000, y: 5000 },
  '0x003': { x: 10000, y: 10000 },
});

@action updateDot(id, properties) {
  const dot = this.dots.get(id);
  Object.assign(dot, properties)
}
```

This should suffice (without testing, no guarantees). Observables by default make their children observable as well if they are non-complex objects. Note that the object.assign in updateDot only works for predefined properties (x and y in this case). MobX cannot yet track non-existing properties. So either make sure all possible prpoerties are declared upfront (with undefined value if needed) or use a map structure for dots as well.

Comment: No reaction when I change dot property ... 
https://runkit.com/ridermansb/react-on-map-object-change/2.0.0

Comment: note that `observe` doesn't have anything to do with `observer`. `autorun` comes closer. Observe only listens to the modifications of the map, not of it contents. MobX at maximum (like with autorun) only tracks what you actually _use_. So if you don't access the `map.get(01).x` property, it won't react to a change in it (after all, why would the value be relevant if you don't use it). I think in your original question what lacks is Matrix being observer, or dereferincing your date first.  I recommended to carefully read: https://mobx.js.org/best/react.html, that should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your Metrix Component. How you use `dots` in it?

MobX will not rerender if you just pass observable value as props.

You have to actually **read** data from it.

In this case your Matrix must be call `dots.get(....)` then your Metrix will rerender when `dots` has been changed.

By the way, your `IndexComponent` and `Map` will not rerender if it just pass down `dots`.

Comment: I need to execute a function every time any data change in Map.. I execute this functions as  `updateData(dots..values())`  in `Matrix` component